# Do we use spatial filtering or frequency filtering for blurring, edge detection?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

In image processing, in which cases do we use spatial filtering and in which cases do we use frequency domain filtering?
What filters do we use in frequency filtering? Can we perform blurring and edge detection using both spatial filtering and frequency filtering?

Answer (score 4):

For any *linear* filter (convolution) you can obtain the same result using spatial domain and frequency domain computations. The convolution with a large kernel is usually more efficient to implement by multiplication in the frequency domain. The convolution with a small kernel is likely more efficient to implement directly in the spatial domain, unless one already has the frequency-domain representation (FFT) of the image available.

For any *non-linear* filter (everything else) you cannot use the frequency domain at all. Fourier analysis is limited to linear systems.